# Freeware to make predefined size screen capture

Tags: windows, screenshot

There are tons of screen capture but I cannot find one that can do  predefined size screen capture. Do you know one that works on Windows 7?

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft [Expression Encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/products/encoderpro_overview.aspx) will allow you set the size of the screen to capture.

Comment: I said FREEWARE not BUYWARE and I don't need video just image :)

Comment: @user75875 - To be fair, you TAGGED freeware.  You didn't really indicate a specific preference.

Comment: OK, sorry.  It allows you to capture for up to ten minutes and works very well.  I did not know that you wanted images though.  Maybe update your post to specify that you want to capture image and not video.  Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

[PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) lets you do this, and it's awfully good.

> Screen Capture
>
> Auto-scroll, dual monitors and sound effect are supported
>    Various output to File, Printer, Office programs, External program
>    Sharing to FTP, Web, E-mail, Facebook and Twitter are supported as well
>
> ```
> Full Screen
> Active Window
> Window Control
> Scrolling Window
> Region, Fixed Region
> FreeHand
> Repeat Last Capture
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Screenspresso](http://www.screenpresso.com/) before with good results.

Some of the [features](http://www.screenpresso.com/features/) (from their website):

1. Capture full screen, part of the screen or a specific window with
   the same shortcut/hot key.
2. Click and drag anywhere on your screen to select a region with pixel perfect accuracy
3. Delay capture for capturing context menu
4. Capture in MP4 format for lightweight files
5. Resize the video at the end and change the format